# Assigning multiple solutions different replacement names

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, replacement

Let's say we are solving a homogeneous differential equation, such as
$$y^{\prime\prime} + a y^{\prime} + b y = 0$$
with characteristic equation
$$s^2 + a s+ b = 0.$$
Using the `Solve` function,

```
sols = Solve[s^2 + a*s + b == 0, s]
```

we get

```
{{s -> 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])}, {s -> 1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])}}.
```

Now, the family of solutions is given by
$$y(t) = C_1 e^{s_1 t} + C_2 e^{s_2 t}$$
where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the roots of the characteristic equation.

How best to automatically substitute `sols`, which has two assignments for `s` into an expression like

```
C1*Exp[s1*t] + C2*Exp[s2*t]
```

or something more general (that adapts to the number of solutions)? All I can come up with are pretty inelegant hacks.

It would nice to give `Solve` an option to return something like

```
{{s[1] -> 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])}, {s[2] -> 1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])}}
```

but I couldn't find an option like this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities. You could do something like

```
sols = Flatten@Module[{i=1}, Solve[s^2 + a*s + b == 0, s] /. s :> s[i++]];
(* {s[1] -> 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b]), s[2] -> 1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
sols = Solve[s^2 + a*s + b == 0, s];
exprs = {c1 Exp[s t], c2 Exp[s t]};
Plus @@ MapThread[#1 /. #2 &, {exprs, sols}]
(* c1 E^(1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b]) t) + c2 E^(1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b]) t) *)
```

Comment: +1 These are both nice! I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else wants to take a crack at it before I accept it as the answer.

Comment: I'm going to choose this as the correct answer because it technically addresses the issue of creating a list of replacement rules for different variables. However, I slightly prefer the approach by bbgodfrey.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is

```
sol = Solve[s^2 + a*s + b == 0, s]//Flatten; 
Sum[C[i] Exp[sol[[i, 2]] t], {i, Length[sol]}]
```

But, why not just

```
DSolve[y''[t] + a y'[t] + b y[t] == 0, y[t], t][[1, 1, 2]]
```

both of which give

```
(* E^(1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b]) t) C[1] + E^(1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b]) t) C[2] *)
```

**Addendum**

A bit more compact is

```
Total[MapIndexed[C[First@#2] Exp[Last@#1 t] &, Solve[s^2 + a*s + b == 0, s], {2}], 2]
```

Comment: I like really like your solution, especially in its first form. It's intuitive for a student. Since I'm teaching, I want to show the steps in addition to the `DSolve` approach. Thanks!

Comment: I have decided to choose the answer by march because it addresses the challenge of creating a replacement list as I requested. However, I prefer this approach by bbgodfrey.

Comment: You made a good choice.  The first solution by @march is compact and creative.